# Oven baked cod fillets get soaked in their own liquid

Tags: baking, fish, cod

I baked cod fillets twice. The first batch was fine, the second had the fish soaked in its own liquid.
(Two different batches from the same shop, salted 1.5 hour before cooking, within expiration date).

I used a basic recipe:

```
cod fillets
olive oil
garlic
parsley
salt, pepper
```

Baked in pre-heated oven @ 180C/fanned air for 10-15 minutes

How can I prevent this loss of water?

Comment: Was it the same batch of fish? And how far in advance did you salt each batch?

Comment: Especially when not the same batch: where did you buy them and how 'old' were they?

Comment: @layna two different batch of cod same shop, salted 1.5 hour before cooking

Comment: @jan all within exp. Date

Comment: Which means you don't know how old both batches were. That could be a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the cod fillets were two different batches, chances are you just where unlucky with the second batch. Even within expiry-date, the amount of water food loses while cooking can vary vastly with age and quality. And even good fish shops can have watery batches at times.

To generally avoid this soaking happening, I would rest the cod on a cooking grate or - this is a personal preference - on some pre-cooked potatoes.

A small factor may be oversalting, but chances are it is actually the cod.